# Can I connect directly to a docker swarm network?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I want a shell inside a Docker Service / Swarm network. Specifically, I want to be able to connect to a database that's inside the network.

From the manager node, I tried:

```
# docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME          DRIVER              SCOPE
481c20b4039a        bridge        bridge              local
2fhe9rtim9mz        my-network    overlay             swarm
```

Then

```
docker run -it --network my-network alpine sh
```

But I get the error:

> docker: Error response from daemon: swarm-scoped network (event-data-core-prod) is not compatible with `docker create` or `docker run`. This network can only be used by a docker service.

Is it possible to somehow start an interactive session that can connect to a network service?

Comment: If you're using 1.13 there is an `--attachable` flag when creating a network that will let ad-hoc (non-service) containers join a network.

Comment: Is there a way to change this for an extant network? Docs don't seem to suggest it. I don't want to stop a whole network just to edit this config value. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Docker Engine [v1.13](https://docs.docker.com/release-notes/docker-engine/#1130-2017-01-18) (like already mentioned by  [johnharris85](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42376274/can-i-connect-directly-to-a-docker-swarm-network?rq=1#comment71905174_42376274)) it [is](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/25962) possible for non-service container to attach to a swarm-mode overlay networks using the `--attachable` commandline parameter when creating the network:

```
docker network create --driver overlay --attachable my-attachable-overlay-network
```

---

Regarding your followup question:

> Is there a way to change this for an extant network?

Yes and no, like I already described in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41847656/network-not-manually-attachable-when-running-one-off-command-against-docker-sw/48404258#48404258) you can make use of the `docker service update` feature:

To update an already running docker service:

1. Create an attachable overlay network:

   ```
   docker network create --driver overlay --attachable my-attachable-overlay-network
   ```
2. Remove the network stack with a disabled "attachable" overlay network (in this example called: `my-non-attachable-overlay-network`):

   ```
   docker service update --network-rm my-non-attachable-overlay-network myservice
   ```
3. Add the network stack with an enabled "attachable" overlay network:

   ```
   docker service update --network-add my-attachable-overlay-network myservice
   ```